# Find any word in a string within another range

Tags: string, excel, text, find

How can I write a formula in Excel-Sheet for the following problem:

I have a range 1 of cells with values like:

> Adidas
>
> Nike USA
>
> Reebok Japan
>
> United Colors of Benetton

etc.

And another range 2 with following

> I love Adidas
>
> How strange is Benetton
>
> What the hell is Reebok
>
> Obama is Democrat President

Now I need to find which cells in range 1 have any word appearing in range 2. So I need to get the following result that would be:

> TRUE (Adidas)
>
> FALSE (no Nike)
>
> TRUE (Reebok)
>
> TRUE (Benetton)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote VBA code to be able to iterate across words in *text_to_find* (the challenging part). I can imagine that some contrived formula could be written. I did not do it myself (it would be most interesting!).

The User Defined Function works for your example. You may have to adapt it slightly, for other cases.

```
Public Function substr_find(ByRef text_to_find As Range, ByRef range_to_search As Range) As Boolean
    ' Create a vector of words to search for
    Dim sep As String
    sep = " "
    Dim words() As String
    words = Split(text_to_find.Value, sep, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    ' Search for the word, exit as True as soon as it is found
    substr_find = False
    Dim word As String
    Dim wordv As Variant
    For Each wordv In words
      word = CStr(wordv)
      If (Not (range_to_search.Find(word) Is Nothing)) Then
        substr_find = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next wordv
End Function
```